# How to wait for action to complete before redirecting in react redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, promise, async-await

I'm trying to log users in based on a isLoggedin state from redux store. My Login Component dispatches the fetchLogin action from the userLogin action mapped to props.

```
const Login = (props) => {
    const [userLogin, setUserLogin] = useState({ email: "", password: "" })

    const getValue = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setUserLogin({
            ...userLogin,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value 
        });
    }

    const makeRequest = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        props.userLogin(userLogin)

        if (props.isLoggedin === true) {
            console.log(Cookie.get('accessToken'))
            props.history.push('/dashboard')
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Form onSubmit={makeRequest}>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                    <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        placeholder="Enter email"
                        onChange={getValue}
                    >
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        placeholder="Enter password"
                        onChange={getValue}
                    >
                    </Form.Control>

                </Form.Group>
                <Button
                    variant="primary"
                    type="submit"
                >
                    Login
            </Button>
            </Form>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isFetching: state.userReducer.isFetching,
    isLoggedin: state.userReducer.isLoggedin,
    isError: state.userReducer.isError,
    errMessage: state.userReducer.errMessage
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    userLogin: (userLogin) => {
        dispatch(fetchLogin(userLogin))
    }
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Login)
```

The problem here is when the user clicks login, the redux action I have which takes care of logging the user in from the backend takes time and the store isn't updated fast enough for the userLogin function to confirm that the user is logged in. I understand this has something to do with promises but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.

You can find my actions below, the only action that matters is the fetchLogin which is the one being dispatched from the login component.

```
export const userLoginRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
        payload: {
            isFetching: true
        }
    };
}

export const userLoginSuccess = (user) => {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
            user: {
                ...user
            },
            isLoggedin: true,
            isFetching: false
        }
    };
}

export const userLoginFailed = () => {
    return {
        type: USER_LOGIN_FAILED,
        payload: {
            isFetching: false,
            isError: true
        }
    };
}

export const fetchLogin = (userLogin) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(userLoginRequest())
    axios.post('/login', {
        email: userLogin.email,
        password: userLogin.password
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
             dispatch(userLoginSuccess(response.data))
            }
        }, err => {
            console.log("Error", err)
         dispatch(userLoginFailed())
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the promise from your action and set `isLoggedin` state after it's resolved:

```
export const fetchLogin = (userLogin) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(userLoginRequest())
  return axios.post('/login', {
      email: userLogin.email,
      password: userLogin.password
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        dispatch(userLoginSuccess(response.data))
      }
      return response; 
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Error", err)
      dispatch(userLoginFailed())
    })
}

// ...

 const makeRequest = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   props.userLogin(userLogin).then(resp => {
     if (props.isLoggedin === true) {
       console.log(Cookie.get('accessToken'))
       props.history.push('/dashboard')
     }
   })
 }
```

Also for this to work you need to update `mapDispatchToProps` to actually return the dispatch:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    userLogin: (userLogin) => dispatch(fetchLogin(userLogin))
});
```

One more thing, I just realised that to properly redirect in this case using the promise from dispatch is actually not necessary since it's possible to track the `isLoggedin` prop in `useEffect`

```
 const makeRequest = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  props.userLogin(userLogin)
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (props.isLoggedin === true) {
    console.log(Cookie.get('accessToken'))
    props.history.push('/dashboard')
  }
}, [props.isLoggedin])
```

Comment: I understand that I need to return a promise but it seems like we're not actually returning a promise, I get an error with .then is not a function.

Comment: `return response;` should be outside of condition, updated the answer.

Comment: Nope, still not working, I'm still getting the same error, however checkout the mapDispatchToProps where useLogin  function is defined, issue seems to be that the promise isn't being return to it directly.

Comment: Ahh, right, you need to use an implicit return there. Updated the answer.

Comment: So it seems to have worked but it's doing the same thing as before, which is not redirecting unless I press enter twice firing off the makeRequest function. I feel like even with the promise being returned I'm missing something, I checked the state of isLoggedin when we press enter and it is set to true so I know the action fired but I'm not sure why it's not redirecting immediately. I feel like we are somehow exiting the makeRequest function.

Comment: It might be that it redirects on the next render, since the data comes from props. I think you could move the redirect logic into `useEffect` hook to properly track it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: You are the MAAAN! Yes, I have thought this might work earlier but I was dumb not to try it. Thank you!