# Best way to dispatch an action client-side upon Sign In using Redux, React, NextAuth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, next-auth

I am writing a web app based on the Spotify API. Once the user logs in using NextAuth, I want the app to automatically load the user's playlists.

I currently have it set up so that there is a button to load playlists and the button does not appear unless the user is logged in - this works and is simple. However, the button is unnecessary. There is no use-case for the app that doesn't begin with loading the user's playlists.

I currently have a thunk action written which was dispatched by the "Load Playlists" button to fetch the playlists asynchronously and add the playlists to the redux state.

I can think of multiple possible options to get the automatic loading to work well, but I imagine there has to be a clean way. NextAuth has the [signIn event callback]https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/events#signin which seems like the right place to start. But since this would be run server-side, it would need some way to contact the client.

Answer (score 2):

Just observe the status in. a useEffect and once the status is authenticated call the load playlist action.

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Component() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()
  
  useEffect(() => {
      if (status === "authenticated") {
           Load_Playlists()
      }
  }, [status])


  return <Main>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what I usually do is save the Jwt on local storage then use a use effect to get it if not existing then get it from the server using the thunk action.
also, see [How to wait for action to complete before redirecting in react redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039450/how-to-wait-for-action-to-complete-before-redirecting-in-react-redux,for) how to define the thunk